# What are the alpha, beta and gamma values used in the Forecast.ETS function in excel?

Tags: excel, smoothing, exponential, forecast, ets

I use forecast.ets function in excel. I want learn what values alpha, beta, gamma parameters which are based on[0,1]

Comment: Have you checked Excel’s explanation for the function? They usually give worked examples as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.